# Batch file malfunctions only when called by VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, process, call

I VB.NET program which calls a batch file. In the batch file there is a line that calls a shortcut. When I run the batch file directly it works exactly how it should. However when it's called by the program there is an error that looks like this:

[image: error message]

I've checked multiple time and there definitely is that file in that path.

In the batch file I call the shortcut like this: `"C:\Apps\Ubuntu.lnk"`

In the VB.NET program I've tried calling the batch with:

`shell("C:\Apps\batchfile.bat")`

`shell("cmd /c C:\Apps\batchfile.bat")`

`process.start(""C:\Apps\batchfile.bat"")`

How is starting a batch file from a VB.NET program different from starting it from explorer or cmd? Does anyone know why this is happening or how I might be able to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial an error, I found the solution:

```
Shell("cmd /c start ""Ubuntu"" ""explorer.exe"" ""C:\Apps\Ubuntu.bat""")
```

This calls explorer.exe which calls the batch file.

Comment: You are calling `cmd` to call `start` to call `explorer` to call batch... Is that the best solution you find??? Why don't you keep `Shell("C:\Apps\batchfile.bat")` in VB and replace `START "Ubuntu" "C:\Apps\Ubuntu.lnk"` in batch? BTW, also I can't understand what is the problem with your initial code. Post your bat code.

Comment: I didn't want to change the batch file code because it worked fine when I launched it directly. I'm not going to distribute this so it doesn't really matter how good the solution is, but I would still like to know how calling a batch file from a vb program is different than starting it via explorer.exe

Comment: the only difference I can think of is the working directory could be different when calling from VB. although, not sure how that would affect a batch file call a file with its full path.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but the bath file does use the full path, and when I tried setting the working directory at the beginning of the batch there was no affect. It's pretty bizarre

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure what is exactly wrong but try using the `start` command as so:

```
start C:\Apps\Ubuntu.lnk
```

That should work fine

Yours, Mona